# Rotate <TR> background color without using for-each

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to set the background color of every other `<TR>` I am not using a for-each loop since I am using a few templates to filter data based on the nodes value.

```
<xsl:template match="NewDataSet">  
<html>
     <body>
    <table width="390" style="text-align:left;">
 <tr>
    <th style="text-align:left;"><span style="font:20px arial; font-weight:bold;">Agent Name</span></th>
    <th style="text-align:center;"><span style="font:20px arial; font-weight:bold;">State</span></th>
    <th style="text-align:center;" ><span style="font:20px arial; font-weight:bold;">Time</span></th>
  </tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:sort select="time" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </table>
```

```
<xsl:template match="AgentSales[State=\'Talking Out\']">
    <tr>
       <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>



<xsl:template match="AgentSales/AgentName">
    <td style="text-align:left;">
        <span style="font:14px arial; font-weight:bold;text-align:center;"> <xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
    </td>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="AgentSales/State">
    <td style="text-align:center;">
        <span style="font:14px arial; font-weight:bold;text-align:center;"> <xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
    </td>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="AgentSales/time">
    <td style="text-align:center;">
        <span style="font:14px arial; font-weight:bold;text-align:center;"> <xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
    </td>

</xsl:template>


   <xsl:template match="AgentSales/Reason | AgentSales"/>
```

here is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <AgentSales>
    <AgentName>MCCALLISTER AARON</AgentName>
    <State>Talking Out</State>
    <Reason />
    <time>9</time>
  </AgentSales>
  <AgentSales>
    <AgentName>APPELHANS BARRY</AgentName>
    <State>Talking Out</State>
    <Reason />
    <time>1</time>
  </AgentSales>
  <AgentSales>
    <AgentName>ARREDONDO KARLA</AgentName>
    <State>Talking Out</State>
    <Reason />
    <time>0</time>
  </AgentSales>
</NewDataSet>
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete XSLT solution, adding just one short template to your existing code. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this in CSS by using `:nth-child([even/odd])` :

```
tr:nth-child(even) td {
    background-color: #fff;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) td {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

However, this will not work on older browsers.
According to [CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/:nth-child](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/:nth-child) it's a CSS3 selector.

Comment: Firefox has supported this since version 3.5

Comment: So I can apply this inline in the XSL file?   Something like:<xsl:template match="AgentSales[State=\'Talking Out\']">
    <tr>
       <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

Comment: <xsl:template match="AgentSales[State=\'Talking Out\']">
    <tr style="nth-child(odd):background-color:#ccc;">
       <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

Comment: No, you should use it in a `<style>` element, or in a .css file. You shouldn't use inline styles. As some people would call it, it's a bit "2000".

Answer (score 1):

**Here is the classic XSLT solution**:

**Replace**:

```
    <xsl:apply-templates> 
        <xsl:sort select="time" data-type="number" order="descending"/> 
    </xsl:apply-templates>
```

**with**:

```
        <xsl:variable name="vrtfResult">
         <xsl:apply-templates>
           <xsl:sort select="time" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
         </xsl:apply-templates>
       </xsl:variable>

       <xsl:apply-templates select="ext:node-set($vrtfResult)/tr"/>
```

**Replace your `<stylesheet>` element with**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common"
 xmlns:my="my:my"  extension-element-prefixes="ext my">

 <my:colors>
  <c>#ffff</c>
  <c>#cccc</c>
 </my:colors>

 <xsl:variable name="vColors"
      select="document('')/*/my:colors/*"/>
```

**Finally, add this template**:

```
 <xsl:template match="tr">
  <xsl:variable name="vPos" select="position()"/>
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
  <xsl:attribute name="bgcolor">
    <xsl:value-of select="$vColors[($vPos mod 2)+1]"/>
  </xsl:attribute>

  <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
 </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
```

**The complete XSLT code becomes**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common"
 xmlns:my="my:my"  extension-element-prefixes="ext my">

 <my:colors>
  <c>#ffff</c>
  <c>#cccc</c>
 </my:colors>

 <xsl:variable name="vColors"
      select="document('')/*/my:colors/*"/>

 <xsl:template match="NewDataSet">
       <html>
            <body>
             <table width="390" style="text-align:left;">
                          <tr>
                            <th style="text-align:left;"><span style="font:20px arial;
font-weight:bold;">Agent Name</span></th>
                            <th style="text-align:center;"><span style="font:20px arial;
font-weight:bold;">State</span></th>
                            <th style="text-align:center;" ><span style="font:20px arial;
font-weight:bold;">Time</span></th>
                           </tr>

                <xsl:variable name="vrtfResult">
                 <xsl:apply-templates>
                   <xsl:sort select="time" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
                 </xsl:apply-templates>
               </xsl:variable>

               <xsl:apply-templates select="ext:node-set($vrtfResult)/tr"/>
             </table>
           </body>
        </html>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="tr">
  <xsl:variable name="vPos" select="position()"/>
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
  <xsl:attribute name="bgcolor">
    <xsl:value-of select="$vColors[($vPos mod 2)+1]"/>
  </xsl:attribute>

  <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
 </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="AgentSales[State='Talking Out']">
   <tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </tr>
 </xsl:template>

       <xsl:template match="AgentSales/AgentName">
           <td style="text-align:left;">
               <span style="font:14px arial;
font-weight:bold;text-align:center;"> <xsl:value-of
select="."/></span>
           </td>

       </xsl:template>

       <xsl:template match="AgentSales/State">
           <td style="text-align:center;">
               <span style="font:14px arial;
font-weight:bold;text-align:center;"> <xsl:value-of
select="."/></span>
           </td>

       </xsl:template>

       <xsl:template match="AgentSales/time">
           <td style="text-align:center;">
               <span style="font:14px arial;
font-weight:bold;text-align:center;"> <xsl:value-of
select="."/></span>
           </td>

       </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="AgentSales/Reason | AgentSales"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<NewDataSet>
  <AgentSales>
    <AgentName>MCCALLISTER AARON</AgentName>
    <State>Talking Out</State>
    <Reason />
    <time>9</time>
  </AgentSales>
  <AgentSales>
    <AgentName>APPELHANS BARRY</AgentName>
    <State>Talking Out</State>
    <Reason />
    <time>1</time>
  </AgentSales>
  <AgentSales>
    <AgentName>ARREDONDO KARLA</AgentName>
    <State>Talking Out</State>
    <Reason />
    <time>0</time>
  </AgentSales>
</NewDataSet>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <table width="390" style="text-align:left;">
         <tr>
            <th style="text-align:left;"><span style="font:20px arial; font-weight:bold;">Agent Name</span></th>
            <th style="text-align:center;"><span style="font:20px arial; font-weight:bold;">State</span></th>
            <th style="text-align:center;"><span style="font:20px arial; font-weight:bold;">Time</span></th>
         </tr>
         <tr bgcolor="#cccc">

            <td style="text-align:left;"><span style="font:14px arial; font-weight:bold;text-align:center;">MCCALLISTER AARON</span></td>

            <td style="text-align:center;"><span style="font:14px arial; font-weight:bold;text-align:center;">Talking Out</span></td>


            <td style="text-align:center;"><span style="font:14px arial; font-weight:bold;text-align:center;">9</span></td>

         </tr>
         <tr bgcolor="#ffff">

            <td style="text-align:left;"><span style="font:14px arial; font-weight:bold;text-align:center;">APPELHANS BARRY</span></td>

            <td style="text-align:center;"><span style="font:14px arial; font-weight:bold;text-align:center;">Talking Out</span></td>


            <td style="text-align:center;"><span style="font:14px arial; font-weight:bold;text-align:center;">1</span></td>

         </tr>
         <tr bgcolor="#cccc">

            <td style="text-align:left;"><span style="font:14px arial; font-weight:bold;text-align:center;">ARREDONDO KARLA</span></td>

            <td style="text-align:center;"><span style="font:14px arial; font-weight:bold;text-align:center;">Talking Out</span></td>


            <td style="text-align:center;"><span style="font:14px arial; font-weight:bold;text-align:center;">0</span></td>

         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I like CSS solutions for style, but for general questions about this subject and without extension function, you would need to use a push style like (Dimitre's stylesheet borrowed):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my"
 exclude-result-prefixes="my">
    <my:colors>
        <c>#ffff</c>
        <c>#cccc</c>
    </my:colors>
    <xsl:variable name="vColors" select="document('')/*/my:colors/*"/>
    <xsl:template match="NewDataSet">
        <html>
            <body>
                <table width="390" style="text-align:left;">
                    <tr>
                        <th style="text-align:left;">
                            <span style="font:20px arial; font-weight:bold;"
                             >Agent Name</span>
                        </th>
                        <th style="text-align:center;">
                            <span style="font:20px arial; font-weight:bold;"
                             >State</span>
                        </th>
                        <th style="text-align:center;" >
                            <span style="font:20px arial; font-weight:bold;"
                             >Time</span>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:apply-templates 
                         select="AgentSales[State='Talking Out']">
                        <xsl:sort select="time" 
                                  data-type="number"
                                  order="descending"/>
                    </xsl:apply-templates>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="AgentSales">
        <xsl:variable name="vPos" select="position()"/>
        <tr bgcolor="{$vColors[($vPos mod 2)+1]}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="AgentSales/*">
        <xsl:variable name="vAlign"
                      select="concat(substring('left',
                                               1 div (self::AgentName)),
                                     substring('right',
                                               1 div not(self::AgentName)))"/>
        <td style="text-align:{$vAlign};">
            <span style="font:14px arial; font-weight:bold;text-align:center;">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </span>
        </td>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="AgentSales/Reason"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me with the follow up question. For some reasone the rotating bg color didnt work untill I made #ffff and #cccc  to #ffffff and #cccccc hex values.