# Namespace 'http://exslt.og/common' ERROR

Tags: xml, xslt

I have two servers my test server "Sever 1" is online with no firewall. Server 2 (Production) is behind a firewall. Below is the code that is giving the following error:   Namespace 'http://exslt.org/common' does not contain any functions
This error only show on Server 2. If I try browsing to http://exslt.org/common on either browser the page is not there.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common"
 xmlns:my="my:my"  extension-element-prefixes="ext my">
```

I got the above code from a very helpful person on stackoverflow and I am 95% it was working on Serer2 but now I'm just getting the error. the rest of the code is below:  PLEASE HELP I am pulling my hair out haha.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common"
 xmlns:my="my:my"  extension-element-prefixes="ext my">

 <my:colors>
  <c>#fff</c>
  <c>#ccc</c>
 </my:colors>

 <xsl:variable name="vColors" select="document(\'\')/*/my:colors/*"/>

 <xsl:template match="NewDataSet">
       <html>
            <body>
             <table width="390" style="text-align:left;" cellspacing="0">
                          <tr>
                            <th style="text-align:left;"><span style="font:20px arial;
font-weight:bold;">Agent Name!</span></th>
                            <th style="text-align:center;"><span style="font:20px arial;
font-weight:bold;">State</span></th>
                            <th style="text-align:center;" ><span style="font:20px arial;
font-weight:bold;">Time</span></th>
                           </tr>

                <xsl:variable name="vrtfResult">
                 <xsl:apply-templates>
                   <xsl:sort select="time" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
                 </xsl:apply-templates>
               </xsl:variable>

               <xsl:apply-templates select="ext:node-set($vrtfResult)/tr"/>
             </table>
           </body>
        </html>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="tr">
  <xsl:variable name="vPos" select="position()"/>
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
  <xsl:attribute name="bgcolor">
    <xsl:value-of select="$vColors[($vPos mod 2)+1]"/>
  </xsl:attribute>

  <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
 </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="AgentSales[State=\'Talking Out\']">
   <tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </tr>
 </xsl:template>

       <xsl:template match="AgentSales/AgentName">
           <td style="text-align:left;">
               <span style="font:14px arial;
font-weight:bold;text-align:center;"> <xsl:value-of
select="."/></span>
           </td>

       </xsl:template>

       <xsl:template match="AgentSales/State">
           <td style="text-align:center;">
               <span style="font:14px arial;
font-weight:bold;text-align:center;"> <xsl:value-of
select="."/></span>
           </td>

       </xsl:template>

       <xsl:template match="AgentSales/time">
           <td style="text-align:center;">
               <span style="font:14px arial;
font-weight:bold;text-align:center;"> <xsl:value-of
select="."/></span>
           </td>

       </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="AgentSales/Reason | AgentSales"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The problem is that your are using an extension function wich must be implemented by your XSLT processor. Mostly every XSLT processor implement `node-set()` extension function, but they might differ in the chosen namespace URI. Other approach would be to use a push style like in my answer for your own question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4464490/rotate-tr-background-color-without-using-for-each/4466261#4466261

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for an explanation and suggested solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your problem is** that the XSLT processor that runs on one ov the servers implements the `node-set()` extension function of EXSLT, while the other XSLT processor (running on the other server) does not implement this extension function.

**The solution is** to use the same XSLT processor on both servers, if possible.

If this cannot be done, find out the namespace (and name) for the `xxx:node-set()` extension function that is supported on the second server, and replace:

```
xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common"
```

with

```
xmlns:ext="{the-exact-namespace-to-be-used-for-this-XSLT-processor}"
```